# NEP-141 fungible token AssemblyScript implementation

Tags: nearprotocol

Was hoping to find NEP-141 examples in AssemblyScript. I'm currently refactoring an NEP4 contract and could use any code examples in AssemblyScript to help lessen some confusion. I do realize Rust is a more secure option for dealing with tokens. This is for learning purposes only, and will remain on testnet. Any help is very much appreciated.

Currently, I'm using these for reference:

https://learn.figment.io/network-documentation/near/tutorials/1-project_overview/2-fungible-token

https://nomicon.io/Standards/FungibleToken/Core.html

Comment: NEP171 examples in assemblyscript will be just as helpful too!

Comment: For `NEP-171` and it's extensions you can take some inspiration from my code: https://github.com/devey/YSN/blob/master/contracts/SHARE/assembly/index.ts

I also started writing parts of the `NEP-141` in AssemblyScript.

Comment: oh is this what you're having issues with in your SO post from earlier?

Comment: Yes, there is multiple contracts.

Comment: What's latest on these, do you have any AssemblyScript NFT code posted on github?

Comment: Found implementation at https://github.com/curaOS/source/tree/master/packages/contracts/as/NFT

What is the intended license for this code? package.json says MIT, is this correct?